# SpringBoot authentication DataSource

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-security, spring-boot, c3p0

I'm using SpringBoot, Spring Security, C3P0 and JPA hibernate in my application.

How can I tell SpringBoot to try to authentificate the user using a different DataSource than the one supplied in the .properties file.

**EDIT 1**

```
public class AuthFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {
    private boolean postOnly = true;

    public AuthFilter() {
        super(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/login", "POST"));
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException {
        if (postOnly && !request.getMethod().equals("POST")) {
            throw new AuthenticationServiceException(
                    "Authentication method not supported: "
                            + request.getMethod());
        }

        String email = request.getParameter("username");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");

        String username = email.substring(0, email.indexOf("@"));
        String db = email.substring(email.indexOf("@") + 1, email.lastIndexOf("."));

        if (username == null) {
            username = "";
        }

        if (password == null) {
            password = "";
        }

        username = username.trim();
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authRequest = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                username, password);

        // Here I should change the DataSource before the authentication occurs.
        return this.getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(authRequest);
    }

    public void setPostOnly(boolean postOnly) {
        this.postOnly = postOnly;
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll probably need to setup another data-source if you want to use a different data-source for your authentication in Spring Security.

Comment: I actually determine the datasource name  from the username when he attempts to login, with an AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter, but i can't find a way to either call my CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver or MultiTenantConnectionProvider to change the database before the authentification occurs.

Comment: Post some code, I don't know Spring Boot at all, but do know Spring Security, Hibernate and C3P0.

Comment: I edited my post, the db String is the name of the database that should be used.

Comment: Is there something stopping you from implementing your own custom authentication manager and then implementing your login there ?

Comment: I just finished doing so, it's not that pretty, i had to do so since i didn't find another other solution, I created a sessionFactory and a datasource in my  AuthenticationProvider for the client and search for him manually rather than using my service. It worked.

Answer (score 0):

*Solution by OP*

> I created a `sessionFactory` and a datasource in my `AuthenticationProvider` for the client and searched for him manually rather than using my service. It worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use different system, You can call a API within your custom authenticationProvider by using ReST Template.So through a ReST API , you can authenticate. Some thing like this,

```
public static final String REST_SERVICE_URI = "<your microservice end 
  point>";
Users authApiObj = new Users();
authApiObj.username = "username";
authApiObj.password = "username";

RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(); 
HttpEntity<Object> request = new HttpEntity<Object>(authApiObj, headers);
String responseString = restTemplate.postForObject(REST_SERVICE_URI, 
   request, String.class);
```

Otherwise You need to configure spring cloud config server and launch your spring boot application optionally and access the dynamic properties loaded in your application from configured spring config server

Answer (score 0):

I know question was asked way back; but might help someone else looking for an answer(*answer might be bit long*).

NOTE: The BELOW LOGIC DOES NOT SWITCH TO MULTIPLE DB SOURCES WITHIN SAME REQUEST. JPA is connected to main datasource pointed in `application.properties` file. Below logic simply uses JDBC TEMPLATE FOR ADDITIONAL DB Connection.

SpringBoot 2.0.1 introduced [`AbstractRoutingDataSource`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/lookup/AbstractRoutingDataSource.html) using which one can, dynamically use appropriate dataSource per request. The `datasource` is of type `Map<Object, Object>`.

Essentially, the dataSource map should contain the connection identifier as key and datasource as value. There are 2 ways to populate the Map.

1st way: Here dataSourceMap will be populated at application start only. (Assuming all Users exist in a *different* single DB (other than main DB), this method should be sufficient.)

a. Create a configuration file `ClientDataSourceConfig.java` which is loaded on application start, where dataSourceMap is manually prepared and also set the default target DB source for JPA.

ClientDataSourceConfig.java:

```
import com.company.tripmis.datasource.ClientDataSourceRouter;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class ClientDataSourceConfig {

    @Value("${spring.datasource.driver}")
    private String driver;

    @Value("${spring.datasource.url}")
    private String url;

    @Value("${spring.datasource.username}")
    private String username;

    @Value("${spring.datasource.password}")
    private String password;

    public ClientDataSourceRouter dataSource;

    @Bean(name = "getDataSource") // <-- IMP: Bean and Returning manually created ClientDataSourceRouter
    public ClientDataSourceRouter getDataSource() throws Exception {
        dataSource = new ClientDataSourceRouter();

        // Here we are initialising default DB from application.properties file manually.

        dataSource.init(driver, url, username, password);
        return dataSource;
    }

}
```

b. In `ClientDataSourceRouter`, prepare the datasource map by either connecting to main DB (for multitenant systems) or statically mention additional DB(s) and add it to `dataSourceMap` and also set the default DB to be used (ideally main DB).

ClientDataSourceRouter.java:

```
import static com.company.tripmis.utils.Helpers.prepareDataSourceConnectionObj;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import com.company.tripmis.model.entites.GlobalSetup;

import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.lookup.AbstractRoutingDataSource;

public class ClientDataSourceRouter extends AbstractRoutingDataSource {

    private HashMap<Object, Object> dataSourceMap;

    public void init(String driver, String url, String username, String password) throws Exception {
        try {
            DriverManagerDataSource defaultDataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
            defaultDataSource.setDriverClassName(driver);
            defaultDataSource.setUrl(url);
            defaultDataSource.setUsername(username);
            defaultDataSource.setPassword(password);

            /**
             * I am using below code for MultiTenantDB connection and hence reading and
             * initialise multiple DBs but, for the above case, assuming User authentication
             * DB is ONE seperate DB, you can replace the below JDBC Template part with User
             * Authentication DB connection info and add it to this.dataSourceMap with key.
             */
            JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(defaultDataSource);
            List<GlobalSetup> globalSetupList = jdbcTemplate
                    .query("SELECT `id`, `key`, `value`, `description` FROM global_setup;", (rs, rowNum) -> {
                        GlobalSetup globalSetup = new GlobalSetup();
                        globalSetup.setId(rs.getString(1));
                        globalSetup.setKey(rs.getString(2));
                        globalSetup.setValue(rs.getString(3));
                        globalSetup.setDescription(rs.getString(4));
                        return globalSetup;
                    });

            this.dataSourceMap = new HashMap<>();
            for (GlobalSetup globalSetup : globalSetupList) {
                String key = globalSetup.getKey();
                String configString = globalSetup.getValue();
                DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = prepareDataSourceConnectionObj(configString);
                this.dataSourceMap.put(key, dataSource);
            }
            // Comment till here and add single DB connection info to DBMap.

            this.setTargetDataSources(dataSourceMap);
            this.setDefaultTargetDataSource(defaultDataSource);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw ex;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Object determineCurrentLookupKey() {
        return ClientDataSourceContext.getClientDatabase();
    }

    public HashMap<Object, Object> getDataSources() {
        return this.dataSourceMap;
    }
}
```

2nd Way: For dynamically updating dataSourceMap, create a Filter which will read from DB on every request and update the same. (Should use [caching](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-evict-cache) for the same, so that, DB is not hit on every request, and update the CacheBucket periodically.)

Now that, multiple DB connections are added to datasourceMap at application start, all we need to do is use `JDBCTemplate` connection for User Authentication where required.

This can be either done by intercepting HttpRequest using Filters Or HTTPInterceptors or at `Controller`/`Service` layer depending on the need.

Below **pseudo** code does Authentication at `Filter` level.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import com.company.tripmis.datasource.ClientDataSourceContext;
import com.company.tripmis.datasource.ClientDataSourceRouter;
import com.company.tripmis.model.pojo.ErrorModel;
import com.company.tripmis.model.pojo.ResponseModel;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@Order(2)
public class RequestDataSourceFilter implements Filter {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        String companyId = httpRequest.getRequestURI().split("/")[1];

        ClientDataSourceRouter clientDataSourceRouterObj = (ClientDataSourceRouter) applicationContext
                .getBean("getDataSource");
        HashMap<Object, Object> dataSourcesMap = clientDataSourceRouterObj.getDataSources();
        // Some of the following code is for MultiTenant, if not needed, please ignore
        if (dataSourcesMap.get(companyId) == null) {
            ResponseModel responseModel = new ResponseModel();
            ErrorModel errorModel = new ErrorModel();
            errorModel.setCode("DB_RES_NOT_FND");
            errorModel.setMessage("The DB schema mapping not found for the given: " + companyId);
            responseModel.setSuccess(false);
            responseModel.setMessage("Requested DB resource not found");
            responseModel.setError(errorModel);
            ((HttpServletResponse) response).setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            ((HttpServletResponse) response).setStatus(400);
            response.getOutputStream().write(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(responseModel).getBytes());
            return;
        } else {
            String username = ""; // Read username from request
            JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate((DataSource) dataSourcesMap.get(companyId));
            String sqlQuery = "select * from user where username = ?";
            // Prepare the query
            List<Model> userList = jdbcTemplate.query(sqlQuery, new Object[] { username },
                    new UserAuthMapper());
            // Replace with proper query and create a custom mapper as required.
            // And continue with the authentication here.
        }
        ClientDataSourceContext.setClientName(companyId);
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

The above userList(not a list) will have the user details, which can be used to perform authentication.

One can extend the above logic to switch to a different DB(datasources) per request(Ideally for Multitenant system, where baseUrl defines the DB to be used for that request lifecycle).

The `@Bean(name = "getDataSource")` has to be added as `@DependsOn` to application file, so that, init method runs during application start.

Hope the above answer helps at least give some basic understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Need to write a **CustomDataSourceAuthnticationProvider**.

References:

https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/tree/master/spring-security-modules/spring-security-mvc-boot

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-authentication-with-a-database